# C# thread dispatcher

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a delegate function declared in the View (Window).

The delegate function is executed in a other class. But when i run the application and I the delegate function gets called i get the following error:

> Exception types:
>   System.invalidoperationException
>
> Exception sources: WindowBase
>
> Exception stack traces:
>   System.Windows.threading.dispatcher.VerifyAcess()
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherObject.VerifyAccess()
>   System.windows.Media.visual.verifyAPIReadWrite()
>   ....

Answer (score 2):

This means that a function running in one thread is accessing a DispatcherObject "owned" by a different thread.  DispatcherObjects (including DependencyObjects such as Visuals) can only be accessed from the thread where they were created.  So I am guessing you are running your delegate on a different thread, e.g. via the thread pool or a BackgroundWorker.

The solution is to use Dispacther.Invoke or BeginInvoke when accessing properties or methods of the Visual.  For example:

```
private void ThreadMethod()
{
  // ...this is running on a thread other than the UI thread...
  _myVisual.Dispatcher.Invoke(DoSomethingWithMyVisual);
}

private void DoSomethingWithMyVisual()
{
  // because it has been called via Invoke, this will run on the UI thread
  _myVisual.PartyOn();
}
```

Comment: Or more tersely:

_MyVisual.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => _MyVisual.PartyOn()));